# How to stop Finder from jumping to folder when dragging and dropping?

Tags: finder

Is there a way so Finder won't automatically jump to the folder when dragging and dropping files from one folder to another that's located in the side bar?

I usually just go through my downloads folder and then sort my files manually, but it's a hassle that I always manually have to go back to the download folder to process the next file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either disable spring-loading delay or extend the reaction/response time. In older systems the settings are available in the Finder Preferences > General or in newer systems in System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad:

[image: System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad]

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that even after disabling spring-loading, you can always trigger the spring-load action manually by pressing the space bar.